# Declaring type by pointing to another variable

Tags: typescript

I would swear there exists a way to declare variable in TS in such a way:

```
const X = 1;
let y: typeof X;
```

However, this does not compile and I couldn't find the correct syntax anywhere.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes it does compile. It should work just fine : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20X%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20typeof%20X%3B

Comment: I tried in Typescript version 3.1.6, and it does compile fine. If you are using older version, please upgrade it.

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: I'm sorry all you guys for the hassle; my mistake. I was trying to do something different and forgot to double-check it before posting. Sorry again :(